# Why is it that when I rotate an image, it overlaps over my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I what the images to be rotated a couple degrees, however, whenever I change the rotate property in  css, the image begins to stick to the top of the page and overlap the nav bar.

How can I get the image rotated without having it overlap?

Below is the code

HTML Code Block

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <Title>OTF Official Website</Title>
    <link href = "OTFstyle.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <script src = "OTFscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "header">
        <img src = "icons/otflogo.png" alt = "Logo" id = "logo">
    </div>

    <div class = "toolbar">
    
        <div class = "home">
            <img src = "icons/home.png" alt = "Home" id = "homeicon"> 
            <p id = "text">Home</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class = 'ppl'>
            <img src = "icons/ppl.png" alt = "Members" id = "personicon">
            <p id = "text">Members</p>
        </div>

        <div class = "cam" >
            <img src="icons/cam.png" alt = "Pics and Videos" id = "camicon">
            <p id = "text2"> Pics</p>
        </div>

        <div class = "mem">
            <img src = "icons/mem.png" alt = "Memories" id = "memoryicon">
            <p id = "text3"> Memories</p>
            
        </div>
    </div>


    
    <div class = "intro">

        <img src = "frames/frame1.png" id = 'frame1'>
        <img src = "frames/frame2.png" id = 'frame2'>

        
             


    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code Block

```css
/*Entire pg*/
html,body{
    background-color: rgb(144, 141, 141);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    
    
}
body{
    height:1000px;
}

/*Div contianing the header*/
.header{
    border:solid;
    height:80px;
    display:flex;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
/*otf logo*/
#logo{
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

/*Div contianing the entire toolbar*/
.toolbar{
    top: 0px;
    position:sticky;
    height:60px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background-color: wheat;
}
/*Div containing Home icon*/
.home{
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    justify-content: center;

  
}

/*Div containing members icon*/
.ppl{
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    justify-content: center;
}

/*Div containing members icon*/
.cam{
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    
    justify-content: center;
}

/*Div containing memories icon*/
.mem{
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    justify-content: center;  
}

/*The icons themselves in the toolbar*/
#homeicon{
    height:40px;
}
#personicon{
    height:40px;
}
#camicon{
    height:40px;
}
#memoryicon{
    height:40px;
    margin-left: 11px;
}
/*Text under home and members icon*/
#text{
    margin-top:0px;
}
/*Text under pics icon*/
#text2{
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
/*Div containing memories icon*/
#text3{
    margin-top:0px; 
}

/*Div containing the images*/
.intro{
    border:solid;
    display:block;
    background-color: white;
    
}

/*First image*/
#frame1{
    height:300px;
    rotate: 50deg;
    
}
/*Second image*/
#frame2{
    height:300px;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
```

I wanted to rotate the image in css, however when I rotate it, the image glitches out and starts to overlap everything which is annoying. Please help

Comment: You're saying it "glitches out." What are we supposed to understand from that? Your image is rotating around its center. That's what `rotate` does, so it's not a glitch if that's what you're seeing. I assume your image is rectangular or square. When you rotate it 50 degrees, that's going to make it taller. I illustrate what I think you're seeing here with a rounded image and a square image: https://jsfiddle.net/pnay51kc/

Comment: When I change the rotate property the image starts to overlap over the nav bar when I scroll. I want to rotate the image without having it overlap over the nav bar when I scroll. Thats my issue. I don't know if I'm just not explaining myself well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your clarification correctly, you need to set the `z-index` of your `<div class="toolbar">` to be a higher value than the image(s) you want to overlay on top of.

I did that here in an example: https://jsfiddle.net/an5m2eqs/

Specifically notice how I set the `z-index` of the `.toolbar` to be `9999` and of the image to be `9998`, which places the toolbar at an incrementally higher level in the stack of elements.

```
/*Div contianing the entire toolbar*/
.toolbar {
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: wheat;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

You can read plenty more about `z-index` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: Omg bro your're a goat. And thanks for the info about the Z index. I never knew that was a thing. I'll make sure to read on that. Thanks again.